# App with darkened navigation and tab bar after send to background

Tags: ios8, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, background-process, multitasking

My app under development is running in foreground on iOS 8.1.1 device. When i double-click the home button to see other apps the screen looks like you see it on the right side of the image. But when my app was in background and an other app is running in foreground, and then after double-clicking the home button and swipe to see my app, then the navigation and tab bar look like darkened or shadowed (see left side of the image). I don't know what it means?!?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did some search and found the answer for question [iOS 7 multitasking switcher: Navbar appears black](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184865/3845832). So switching on extended edges for under top/bottom bars for all controllers in storyboard fixed it.